# Doctorine one-to-many child not found by its id in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have made a standaard one-to-many relation with doctorine in Symfony2. The parent is an ad and the child's are the images. This works fine. Now I want to get one of the child's so I can remove / change it.

I want to get the child by its id with the following code:

```
        $image = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Image')
        ->findOneBy(
            array('id' => $id)
        );
```

Only it returns nothing. If I remove the association with its parent then it is found with the same code.

How is it possible to find the child? Or is this only possible by its parent?

Comment: It should work, probably something is wrong with your code. Without any additional details it is impossible to help you. Consider updating your question with entity definitions etc.

Comment: Your correct, the code works. The problem was a complete different issue in the definition of the Ad entity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a DQL query could cut through the red tape?

```
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->createQuery('SELECT i FROM MyBundle:Image i WHERE id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe I'm not understanding well, but if you want to retrieve an image by its id, it should be more simple to do :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$image = ->getRepository('MyBundle:Image')->find($id);
```

Where $id is the image id, can't you ?